# fOAEP parameter in RSA encryption

Tags: c#, php, rsa

`RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt()` has two parameters: rgb (the data to encrypt), and fOAEP. fOAEP is a boolean value which determines what kind of padding should be used:

```
fOAEP
Type: System.Boolean

true to perform direct RSA encryption using OAEP padding (only available on a computer running Microsoft Windows XP or later); otherwise, false to use PKCS#1 v1.5 padding.
```

It says that `true` will only work on Windows XP or later, but I assume that that doesn't necessarily include Linux and other languages. That being said, this *does* need to work on Linux and with PHP. Given that my two biggest priorities are security, and interoperability with a PHP script, should this value be true of false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all very well documented and conforms to standards on the .NET side, I assume it should be the same on PHP side. Look at this for example:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php

It supports both OAEP and PKCS#1. So you should be fine with either of them. My private opinion is that it is not some exotic stuff like the old .DOC format where interoperability is a nightmare. RSA itself is pretty simple, the padding is just adding some binary bytes, there's a lot of thought behind it but it's very simple.

About which is more secure, see this:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32050/what-specific-padding-weakness-does-oaep-address-in-rsa

Or try to find other cryptographic research. Don't trust what I'm saying :).

EDIT: oops, decryption doesn't seem to support OAEP, one more thing to add to phpwtf.org...

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-decrypt.php

Comment: openssl-public-decrypt is used for signature verification, while OAEP is for encryption only, not for signing.

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky - you should be using `openssl_sign` and `openssl_verify` for signing - not `openssl_public_decrypt` / `openssl_private_encrypt`. With PKCS1 padding one of the padding bytes is supposed to be different when doing signing. At least for interoperability purposes.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I didn't look deep enough in openssl functions list.

Answer (score 1):

You should use OAEP for encryption, it is supported by almost all libraries.
Within PHP, you should use openssl_public_encrypt() for encryption and openssl_private_decrypt() for decryption. They both support OAEP padding.